# ParseException: Unparseable date. What wrong?

Tags: android, simpledateformat

In my android app I have

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy  HH:mm:ss");
Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
  try{
      date = formatter.parse("11/10/2013 08:50:13");
     }
  catch (ParseException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Why I got ??

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "11/10/2013 08:50:13"

Comment: there are 2 spaces in your format ...

Comment: do you have two spaces between yyyy and HH in the SimpleDateFormat constructor?

Comment: you have an extra space between yyyy and HH

Comment: not expected this kind of syntax error from experienced person...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have two spaces between yyyy and HH

Answer (score 0):

you have an extra space between yyyy and HH